# Como acessar um diretório de um site que retorna um erro 403 Forbidden?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

Existe alguma forma de acessar um diretório de um site que retorna um erro 403 Forbiden?

Há alguma forma de fazer isso pelo cUrl ou wget?

Estou precisando acessar esse site ele só me retorna esse erro:

http://sslcdn.r.worldssl.net/

Comment: Tu quer ter acesso a um diretório, é isso? Já tentou configurar no ngnix `autoindex on;` para o diretório que você quer?

Comment: Precisa gerar a chave pra acessar os diretórios ?secure=zKGJFg-sJoPF_dTS1biOFw==,1443066000 ...precisaria saber como geram esse chave

Comment: Depende do que está causando este erro, pode ser configuração no Ngnix, mas se o servidor for like-unix pode ser permissões de pasta, ou seja não tem como acessar, pois isto é uma resposta do servidor para um bloqueio interno. Todas respostas HTTP são respostas para problemas, mas você pode forçar usa-las mesmo que não seja um "problema interno". Como por exemplo o erro 500 é quando um software ou modulo falha e o Ngnix ou apache não consegue resposta. -- Não é possivel forçar passar estas respostas, no caso do 403 se for uma página com autenticação você terá que ter os dados para autenticar.

Comment: código http 403 indica permissão negada.. normalmente quando precisa ter uma autenticação ou simplesmente não é permitido acessar o conteúdo.

Comment: @DanielOmine exatamente o que eu disse, no entanto a situação também pode ocorrer com pastas sem permissão em sistemas like-unix por exemplo